# Setting up an SVN repository for a plug-in that depends on specific versions of another application

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm developing a plug-in for another piece of software, which like most software is periodically released in new versions (2011,2012, 2013 etc..). Specific versions of my plug-in will only be compatible with specific versions of the parent application.

What is the best way to organize my SVN repository to keep track of which version is compatible with what?

I was thinking of a structure like this:

```
Repo\MyProject2012\Trunk
Repo\MyProject2012\Branches
Repo\MyProject2012\Tags
```

Then when the 2013 version of the parent application is release and I need to make a new version of my plug-in I'll copy the `MyProject2012\Trunk` to a new folder `MyProject2013\Trunk` and create corresponding `MyProject2013\Tags` and `MyProject2013\Branches` folders.

I'm not sure how to handle version numbers though. If the last version of the 2012 version of my plug-in is 2.5, should the first 2013 release be 1.0? 2.6? 3.0?

Alternatively, I was also thinking of having a single project folder and tracking the change from the 2012 to 2013 versions of my plug-in through tags in the repository. Yet the switch between 2012 and 2013 will be a major change, as it means my plug-in will need to reference an entirely new API of the parent application. Also that would make it difficult to fix a bug in the 2012 version of my plug-in after I start working on the 2013 version as there will only be one trunk folder.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following structure:

```
project/trunk
...
project/branches/v2012/
project/branches/v2013/
project/branches/v2014/
...
project/tags/v2012.0
project/tags/v2012.1
project/tags/v2012.2
project/tags/v2013.0
project/tags/v2013.1
project/tags/v2014.0
project/tags/v2014.1
project/tags/v2014.2
```

The development workflow may be like this:

1. Version of the plug-in will have the prefix that equals to the compatible version of application. For example `v2014.0` is major release of the plug-in compatible with v2014 of application. 
   Next minor (e.g. bug fix) version of the plug-in will be `v2014.1`.
2. Always develop the new version on the `project/trunk`. Lets assume for example you are developing now towards version `v2014`.
3. When you make a major release, e.g. `v2014` is ready to be released, create a branch `project/branches/v2014/` and at the same time create a tag from this branch: `project/tags/v2014.0`:

   ```
   svn cp project/trunk project/branches/v2014/
   svn cp project/branches/v2014/ project/tags/v2014.0
   ```
4. From this moment the release branch `project/branches/v2014/` will be used for bug fixes for the released version `v2014` and the trunk `project/trunk` will be used for development of the new major version `v2015`
5. When you want to release a bug-fix version of the old release, e.g. `v2014.1` simply create a tag from the release branch:

   ```
   svn cp project/branches/v2014/  project/tags/v2014.1
   ```
6. If you need to create a feature branch for the trunk, create it under `project/branches/`. Introduce an naming convention to distinguish between feature branches and release branches:

   ```
   svn cp project/trunk project/branches/feature_xyz
   ```